# How to embed Google Docs or Office 365 editor?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, office365, google-docs

I've already checked some questions here on SO but couldn't find much help...

This one, for instance, is from 2011:

[Embed Google docs editor into webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226222/embed-google-docs-editor-into-webpage)

My users need to be able to edit their Word documents on my website, just like Google docs editor and Office 365. Since I couldn't find information on how to easily integrate those, my current attempt was to convert the Word document to HTML (using OpenXmlPowerTools.HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml) show it in a HTML editor and after the user edited the content save it back to the file (using NotesFor.HtmlToOpenXml).

Is this going to work? Is there any way to integrate either Google Docs or Office 365 to my website, allowing user to edit their content right there? If not, is it possible to programmatically create a document, send it to Google Docs/Office 365 have the user edit it there and then get the document back to save locally again?

Box and Dropbox have done it:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2015/04/dropbox-and-office-online/

https://www.box.com/blog/introducing-box-for-office-online/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i've been working with is Office365, so my answer is based on that, but i think you would be able to do the same in Google Apps.

Right now it's not possible to embed a document from Office365 in your own website for editing, only for viewing, but i guess this might change at some point.

But what you could do is to create a document, upload it do OneDrive, get a link to that file and make a button to open it in Office Online, after the edit is done, then the file would be on the users OneDrive.

If you would like to get the file to your system, it's just a matter of getting access to the users OneDrive.

Most of the operations can be achieved with the Graph API, http://graph.microsoft.io/, and all of it can be done without the user having to do anything. You just need to get the right permissions for the app that gets acess to Office365.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think I could open that editor in a frame? like iframe? Thanks.

Comment: Right now it is not possible to embed the Office Online editor in an iframe, only a view of the document is embedable.